# PowerShellで途中パスの権限のない場所へのchdir(Set-Location)

Tags: windows, powershell

PowerShell 5.0のpowershell.exeもしくはISEで質問です。

まず下記は期待通りの動作になります。

- `start \\\\machine\dir1\dir2\dir3`
  (エクスプローラでdir3を表示)
- `start \\\\machine\dir1\dir2`
  (エラー ← dir2へのアクセス権限がないので正常動作)
- `ls \\\\machine\dir1\dir2\dir3`
  (dir3の中身が一覧表示される。正常)

ところが、下記はエラーになってしまいます。

- `cd \\\\machine\dir1\dir2\dir3`
  (「パス'\\machine\dir1\dir2'へのアクセスが拒否されました。」)

どうやればdir3にchdir出来るでしょうか？
(Windows7 proです)

Comment: dir2の権限は、どうなっていますか？ cd \\machine\dir1\dir2\dir3 するためには、dir2にrとx（「読み出し」と「実行」）の権限を持っている必要があります。　chmodコマンドで、dir2の権限を 755 に変更すれば、dir3にchdir出来るようになると思います。

Comment: dir2への参照権限追加を管理者にお願いすることが出来ない状況なのです。
Fumu 7さんのコメントを見て思いついて試したのですが、cd \\machine\\dir1\dir2\dir3\dir4 はうまく行きました！
要は親ディレクトリ(というかカレントの".."かな)を参照できればchdir出来るということなのですね。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

コメントより

> はい、それは可能です。 コマンドプロンプトで pushd \machine\dir1\dir2
>   としてZドライブに接続し、そこでpowershellを起動すれば動きます。
>   その後思いついて、ホームディレクトリにdir2へのシンボリックリンク(mklink)を張って、cd
>   "$env:USERPROFILE\dir2" とすることにしました。
>   詳しいことはよくわかりませんが、ドライブ接続(subst)するのもシンボリックリンク張るのも同じようなものなのかもしれま‌​せんね。
>   ありがとうございました。 – [出向者](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19044/%E5%87%BA%E5%90%91%E8%80%85)

Answer (score 0):

未検証なので可能性の話なんですが、一旦ネットワークドライブにセットすることができればいけるかもしれませんね

Comment: はい、それは可能です。
コマンドプロンプトで pushd \\machine\dir1\dir2 としてZドライブに接続し、そこでpowershellを起動すれば動きます。

その後思いついて、ホームディレクトリにdir2へのシンボリックリンク(mklink)を張って、cd "$env:USERPROFILE\dir2" とすることにしました。
詳しいことはよくわかりませんが、ドライブ接続(subst)するのもシンボリックリンク張るのも同じようなものなのかもしれませんね。
ありがとうございました。